# Get file type in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke, file-type

How do i get the file type in Mono? i.e. `"*.txt" => "Text Document"`, `"*.jpg" => "JPEG Image"`. Similar to what `SHFILEINFO.szTypeName` returns with P/Invoke on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cross-platform API for this. On Linux you can use GIO, and there are native APIs on Mac too though I don't know them offhand. On Windows you can P/Invoke from Mono.

Comment: Thank you. I'm adding a reference to GIO docs here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/index.html